# How to delete specific index of dynamic array?

Tags: c++

Let say I don't want to use vector and use dynamic array ( Just a learning purpose). From this dynamic array which I have allocated I want to delete specific index.

```
int * array = new int[10];

delete &array[3];
```

When I try to do this I get SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

How do I delete specific index (lets say index 3 , I know its contiguous memory and it will create hole but just for learning purpose)  like I am trying to do above correctly and why am I getting segmentation fault if this is my memory?

Comment: _this is my memory_ This is memory graciously and temporary granted to you by the memory manager, in most cases.

Comment: *Let say I don't want to use vector and use dynamic array ( Just a learning purpose).* --  A vector isn't doing anything magical.  Whatever vector does to delete in the middle, you have to do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't delete an element of an array. You can only delete what you new'ed. To **remove** an element from an array, copy the higher elements down one slot.

Comment: "You can only delete what you new'ed"  Basically I didn't new'ed &array[3] that's why I can't delete it? But I new'ed array so I can delete array right? Makes sense

Comment: @pokche - exactly. `delete` always and only goes with `new`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The array are stored as continuous memory location. You can't delete from in between.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to have an array of pointers to be able to `delete` a single element of your array.

You can shift all following elements back one place, but reallocation of `new`ed memory is not possible with just the standard tools.

Or you can allocate a new array and copy all elements that you want to it.

But the easiest way is to simply use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).